# run java .class file with external library .jar in golang os/exec

Tags: java, go

With go version is go1.13.4 windows/amd64

Is their any way I could run such command `java -cp .;"lib/calc.jar" Hello` 
Using exec.Command() golang package “os/exec” ?

this command is working fine with cmd or bash

Using windows 10 64bit

This where I got exit status 1

```
out, err := exec.Command("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-13.0.1/bin/javaw.exe", "-cp .;\"lib/calc.jar\" Hello", arg[0]).Output()
```

This line is working fine but without including external library in java code

```
out, err := exec.Command("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-13.0.1/bin/javaw.exe", "Hello", arg[0]).Output()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to break the arguments you wish to pass to the executable, and list each individually.

Try it like this:

```
out, err := exec.Command(
    "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-13.0.1/bin/javaw.exe",
    "-cp", ".;lib/calc.jar", "Hello", arg[0],
).Output()
```